# Assigning data (username and password) with auto-insert-row Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So the story is i'm using google forms to collect details of participants for a feedback survey.

They will fill out things like name, email, age, phone model etc etc and this all gets put into a lovely google spreadsheet.

Within this spreadsheet is a list of pre-determined usernames and passwords that sit in 2 columns.

The trouble is every new response generates a new row, which in turn pushes the usernames and passwords down so i have to cut & paste them up a row.

Is there a way to keep the two columns static (fixed) so new entries (new rows) will be populated with the username and password.

I have searched high on low on google forums and on here, but if you find an issue similar to this it'll be a great help if someobody could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Greggeless

Comment: where is this list ? on what row relative to form answers ? could you show an example without private data ?

Comment: Sorry Serge, its all pretty confidential!
Mogsdad answered it below in a couple of robust ways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, the Forms service doesn't just append responses at the end of the current data; it also inserts a new row into the spreadsheet to be ready for the next submission. In this "Before" screenshot, notice that the "data table" managed by Forms has a grey background, while the additional credential columns don't:

[image: Screenshot 1 - before submission]

Now, the "After" screenshot. Once a couple of forms have been submitted, we've got a gap in the credentials!

[image: Screenshot 2 - after submission]

We can recover from the form submission activity by using an installable Spreadsheet Form Submission trigger function. (See [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) and [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events), if you've never dealt with trigger functions in Google Apps Script before.)

The algorithm we'll use is:

1. Given the range containing the new form submission, `offset` to the right and down to obtain the unused credentials, along with any introduced gaps.
2. Remove rows that have blanks. This is accomplished using javascript tricks including the [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.
3. Clear the original credential range, and update it with the tidied credentials.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Spreadsheet Form Submission installable trigger function.
 * Each form submission will bump the username and password (credential)
 * columns down. This function will close them up again.
 *
 * @param {event} e See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events
 */
function onFormSubmit( e ) {
  var credColumns = 2; // # of columns of credential info to right of form
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var toBottom = sheet.getLastRow() - e.range.getRow() + 1; // # rows from new submission to bottom of sheet
  var credentialRange = e.range.offset(0, e.values.length, toBottom, credColumns);
  var crA1 = credentialRange.getA1Notation();

  // Filter the credentials, removing blanks
  var credentialData = credentialRange.getValues()
                                      .filter(function(cred) {
                                        return cred.join('') != '';
                                      });

  debugger;  // pause if running in debugger

  // Write tidied credentials to spreadsheet
  credentialRange.clearContent();
  credentialRange.offset(0, 0, credentialData.length, credentialData[0].length).setValues(credentialData);
}

/**
 * Form Submission test function, adapted from
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067
 */
function test_onFormSubmit() {
  var extraColumns = 2; // Non-Form columns, to the right
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var numFormColumns = data[0].length - extraColumns;
  var headers = data[0].slice(numFormColumns);
  // Start at row 1, skipping headers in row 0
  for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var e = {};
    e.values = data[row].slice(numFormColumns);
    e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,numFormColumns);
    e.namedValues = {};
    // Loop through headers to create namedValues object
    for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      e.namedValues[headers[col]] = e.values[col];
    }
    // Pass the simulated event to onFormSubmit
    onFormSubmit(e);
  }
}
```

Now after a form is submitted, the sheet gets nicely cleaned up:

[image: Screenshot 3 - Way After]

#### Alternative

If you're convinced that you need to keep those non-form columns in place, you've now got a way to do so. However, consider another way.

Instead of having your unused credentials stacked up waiting for Form Submissions, you could keep them on a separate sheet. Then, using a different form submission trigger function, you would only need to pick the next unused credentials from that sheet, and append them to the new row. Of course, you'd want to mark them as used, as well.

This approach should be more efficient than the code provided above.

#### Why not just delete the added row?

With a one-liner, we could use a trigger function to delete the newly added row:

```
function onFormSubmit( e ) {
  e.range.getSheet().deleteRow(e.range.getRow()+1);
}
```

There is a danger with this approach. Since form submissions are asynchronous, there is a possibility that multiple users may be submitting forms at pretty much the same time. When that happens, this trigger function would be invoked multiple times, and the blind deletion of a row could erase a user's submission.

The Lock Service can't help us with this, either. While we could use Lock to ensure that only one invocation of `onFormSubmit()` was running, we have no control over the form itself, or the insertion of form responses.

Comment: Hi Mogsdad and thanks so much for the in depth reply!

I followed your example (first case) and it works a treat. Now i have a lovely understanding of triggers too. Thanks for the education.

Top dog!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, and welcome to SO! Allow me to echo @Serge_insas, not just to you but to others who read this in future - the question would have been better if it provided a clear example, without any private data. (Like the one in this answer.) I guessed right this time, but it took a long time to develop the scenario, and I might have been wrong. (It DOES happen!) Multiply that by several caring answerers =  a lot of effort! You are never obligated to divulge confidential info, but a better question helps produce a better answer.

Comment: Noted, i'll provide a better story + more information next time. Thanks again for your quick and helpful answers!

Greggless